# MySQL count a boolean field as two different columns

Tags: mysql

Think I have a table with two fields: `ID` and `State`. State value (that is boolean) can be 0 or 1. `ID` isn't unique so the table looks like this:

```
  ID  |  State  |
-----------------
  1   |   true  |
-----------------
  1   |  false  |
-----------------
  2   |  false  |
-----------------
  3   |   true  |
-----------------
  1   |   true  |
```

Now, I want to count every rows group by ID field and have State as two different columns in resultset. So it should look like this:

```
  ID  |  TrueState  |  FalseState  |
------------------------------------
  1   |      2      |       1      |
------------------------------------
  2   |      0      |       1      |
------------------------------------
  3   |      1      |       0      |
```

How to do that?

Comment: I note that you have no PK here - which may prove problematic in future.

Comment: @Strawberry This is just an example. Thanks for noting that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pivot query, which mysql doesn't support. The workarounds get ugly fast, but since you're only going to be generating two new columns, it won't be horribly ugly, just mildly unpleasant:

```
SELECT SUM(State = True) AS TrueState, SUM(State = False) AS FalseState,
    SUM(State is NULL) AS FileNotFoundState
...
```

Basically `state = true` will evaluate to boolean true/false, which MySQL will type-cast to an integer `0` or `1`, which can them be `SUM()`med up.

Comment: If that's 'mildly unpleasant', I'd hate to see what you make of hierarchical queries! ;-)